# sort elements by a difference

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

say I have a list of people of varying ages `int` and income `int`, and I want to sort them as follows:

```
people = [(25, 10000), (45, 22000), (20, 11000), (26, 13000), (27, 11000)]

people_new = [(20, 11000), (25, 10000), (27, 11000), (26, 13000), (45, 22000)]
```

First sort by ages.
Second those whose ages are closest to each other (ie the age difference between each person <= 2) are put in order of incomes. Ages is not so important as long as they're close together in terms of difference.

Can this be done with the `sorted` function on lists?

If I write:
`people_new = sorted(people, key = lambda t: (t[0],t[1]))`
The person with age 27 is out of order so this would be incorrect.

[(20, 11000), (25, 10000), (26, 13000), **(27, 11000)**, (45, 22000)]

Do I need to write a new function? If so is there a short pythonic way of doing this?

**Edit:**
By ages being *close* I mean <= 2 from the last age that has been added to the correctly sorted list.
so age 20 can be added, but since there's no 21 or 22 then 25 becomes the start of the next group and 25, 26, 27,... would be looked at.
If all ages 25 - 45 were included then that would be one group.

Comment: First you need to define what 'close' means exactly. 25-27 is an obvious group in your example, but what if you had all ages from 20 to 27? would 20-27 be a group then? what if you had 20 and then all ages from 25 to 45, would 25-45 be a group? if not, what groups would there be?

Comment: With your comment I don't believe there is anything built in. Your use case seems very specific, so you'll need to implement it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can work from what you provided.

```
people = [(25, 10000), (45, 22000), (20, 11000), (26, 13000), (27, 11000)]

people_by_age = sorted(people, key = lambda t: (t[0], t[1]))
# [(20, 11000), (25, 10000), (26, 13000), (27, 11000), (45, 22000)]

N = len(people_by_age)

for i,_ in enumerate(people_by_age):

    # For all but the last person.
    if i+1 < N:

        # If the current and next persons have a close age.
        if abs(people_by_age[i][0] - people_by_age[i+1][0]) <= 2: 

            # Swap their position in the list based on income.
            if people_by_age[i][1] < people_by_age[i+1][1]:
                temp = people_by_age[i]
                people_by_age[i] = people_by_age[i+1]
                people_by_age[i+1] = temp

print(people_by_age) # by age and income.
# [(20, 11000), (26, 13000), (27, 11000), (25, 10000), (45, 22000)]
```

If you think adding `i+1<N` is annoying, you can also write the code so that it ignores the IndexError we will get at the end. It's a bit less explicit though.

```
for i,_ in enumerate(people_by_age):

    try:      
        ...        
    except IndexError:
        break
```